# How to use Font Awesome on blogger for Free?

Tags: font-awesome, cdn, blogger

How to use Font Awesome CDN on blogger for Free?
As I search on the internet I did not any satisfied result or solution.

Answer (score 0):

Place this:

```
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
```

inside `<head>` section and here is the Font Awesome's Cheatsheet: https://fontawesome.com/v5/cheatsheet

Also, Font Awesome 5 and above needs a `font-weight: 900` in order to display some icons properly, so you'll need to add to your CSS something like

```
i.fa,
i.fas {
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

or if you use the CSS Pseudo-elements with a class, something like:

```
.your_class::before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-weight: 900; 
    content: "\f007";
  }
```

More info: https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/referencing-icons/basic-use
and
https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements